# Inserting a DIV in a GWT Panel

Tags: gwt

I have this DIV on my application jsp page which I need to "inject" in to a GWT VerticalPanel. Coded on top of the iframe tag which contains "__gwt_historyFrame" :

**index.jsp**

```
<div class="footer" id="footer" style="display:none">
        <p>Copyright © 2012 MyCompany. All Rights Reserved.</p> 
        <a href="#">FAQ</a>
        <a href="#">Privacy</a>
        <a href="#">API</a>
        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
</div>
```

I am inserting the DIV to the view with this code:

```
DivElement footer = (DivElement) document.getElementById("footer");
verticalPanel.getElement().appendChild(footer);
```

However it does not show up, although the `getElementById` does not return `null`

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things:

- you have to remove the `display: none` of the `footer`: `footer.getStyle().clearDisplay()`
- `VerticalPanel` is an HTML table, and adding a `div` to a `table` is likely to not work.

If I were you, I'd rather use `HTML.wrap(footer)` or `HTMLPanel.wrap(footer)` and add that widget to the `VerticalPanel`, as a widget.